# DisplayPort not working on MacMini

Tags: mac, display, displayport, mac-mini

I am currently using a MacMini (Late 2014) with a BenQ BL2420PT Monitor.
I connect them over a Thunderbolt(the old mini-DisplayPort) to DisplayPort cable.

Both Mac and monitor are 6 Months old and I have used them almost every day. But a week ago the monitor didn't show the Apple logo during boot and this morning the monitor just said "no signal detected" for about half an hour.

I already tried booting into safe mode and into recovery mode, but there is nothing showing up.

Mac and monitor are still working because I am able to connect to the Mac via SSH and connecting the monitor to my Windows laptop (VGA to VGA) still works.

Any help would be appreciated

## SOLUTION

The Mini-DisplayPort Thunderbolt connectors are hard to push in sometimes. The problem was that the cable wasn't plugged in all the way and therefore only sometimes got a signal.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have the same problem with Late 2012 -- by unknown reason the monitor says 'no cable connected' and cannot turn on.
The only solution I found is turn off the monitor via black toggle switch (not a sensor button on front panel) and wait some time.